# Running OpenWRT in linux via VirtualBox: resize vdi step

Tags: linux, virtualbox, openwrt

I am trying to run OpenWRT in Ubuntu using VirtualBox and I am following [this tutorial](https://i12bretro.github.io/tutorials/0114.html). I don't have access to a Window computer so I can't run `vboxmanage.exe`.

I was able to use this to convert `.img` to `.vdi` by using this command:

```
# instead of vboxmanage.exe converted ...
qemu-img convert
```

But I am not sure how to resize the `.vdi`  in linux

```
# vboxmanage.exe modifyhd
# what is the equivalent in linux?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have VirtualBox installed on your Ubuntu machine you can follow the tutorial directly.  The command on Linux is `VBoxManage` (capital letters are important).  You can resize the hard drive with:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd --resize 512 openwrt.vdi
```

You also can convert `.img` to `.vdi` using VirtualBox instead of QEMU:

```
VBoxManage convertdd openwrt-19.07.6-x86-64-combined-ext4.img openwrt.vdi
```